# "Charset missing or incomplete" error during creating PDF/A by pdfx.sty

Tags: pdf, pdf-a

I'm trying to compile my thesis written in LaTeX to PDF/A format as required by our university. I used `pdfx` package. However, I got some errors when doing the preflight check of the generated PDF files in Adobe Acrobat:

"Charset missing or incomplete for Type 1 font"

It seems that the font family I used for my thesis is not completely included in the PDF file. Anyone know how to fix this problem?

By the way, I use Time New Man (`\usepackage{txfonts}`) font for my thesis.

Comment: Have you included `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}` in your preamble?

Comment: I tried with it. But still not work.

Comment: I belief I read somewhere that the `pdfx` package can be a bit unstable, but I don't know much about it. I personally convert files to PDF/A with Acrobat Professional. Could you please post a working MWE that includes your documentclass, only the packages used to reproduce the problem and some content to highlight the issue?

Comment: With no MWE, this is 'too localized' I'm afraid. Request reopening if one is available.